# to vary the severity of the endogeneity problems

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, endogeneity

I have the following regression
$$y_i=a+bx_i+cz_i+dw_i$$

a, b, c, d are coefficients. x is endogenous.z and w are exogenous to errors. My question:

What parameters could be adjusted to vary the severity of the endogeneity problems in the regression?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about $w$ for the moment, since the two regressor case is already complicated.

The endogeneity bias from omitting $x$ will be a function of

1. The magnitude and sign of the correlation between $x$ and the exogenous variable $z$
2. The magnitude and sign of $b$

Comment: well, how can adjust it? which case I have more severe problem? which case I have less severe problem?

Comment: @Example Presumably, you are simulating this data, so you can play around with the parameters I listed. There is also a formula for omitted variable bias that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). The notation is different, but the bias there is proportional to the product of (1) and (2).

Comment: Hi again, I have one more question. I have these models. $$y_i=a_1+b_1x_i+c_1z_i+d_1w_i+u_1$$

$$x_i=a_2+b_2y_i+c_2z_i+d_2w_i+u_2$$  As I said z and w are exogenous. And I generate them and error randomly in R. But how to create x and y by using z and w and attaining some numbers for coefficients. I cannot imagine how to create x and y in R..

Comment: I guess I should use the reduced form. But I don't know how to do it. Please give me a hint or something else. I should put y in the first regression into the second retrogression. And I solve it simultaneously?

Comment: Solve for the endogenous variables as a function of exogenous variables and the errors, simulate, and solve back.